# How do I create a search form for my posts with Sinatra and Sequel?

Tags: ruby, forms, search, sinatra, sequel

I am new to Ruby, and am using Sinatra and Sequel. I'm trying to implement a form to search through the title of my posts.

I'm doing this in my controller:

```
post '/search'  do
@post = Post.all(:Title.like => "%#{params[:query]}%")
erb :layout
end
```

And I'm doing this in my layout.erb:

```
<form action="/search" method="get">
 <input type="text" name="query"/><br />   
 <input type="submit" />
</form>
<% if @results %>
 <table>
  <%@results.each do |r|%>
  <tr valign="top">
  <td><%=r.Title%></td>
  </tr>
  <%end%>
 </table>
<% end %>
```

When I submit, this is the URL I get directed to:

```
http://localhost:4567/search?query=post
```

but it displays the "Sinatra doesn't know this ditty." screen.

What am I missing here?

Comment: It's important to use the right terminology. Sequel isn't a database, it's an [Object-Relational-Mapper](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping), which is like a very-smart database interface layer. Sequel sits between your code and the database.

Comment: Yeah, i meant that. Thank you for you correction. Do you have any idea for my problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your form is doing a HTTP GET

```
<form action="/search" method="get">
```

but your Sinatra action is defined to receive HTTP POST requests.

```
post '/search'  do
```

I think what is confusing you is that you have a class named Post. The get and post in the actions are not class names, but REST actions. Review [routing](http://sinatra-book.gittr.com/#routing).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But, my POST in the POST.all is actually a class name for the posts that i have used, and the GET AND POST used for the routes and the form are REST actions. If you could help me with this search please. I could give you my repository so you can try it yourself so you can see my problem better.

Comment: This answer is explaining the problem, so read carefully what is said in the answer. `post '/search'` has *nothing* to do with your database. It has *everything* to do with the way Sinatra reacts when the browser sends the data to Sinatra. The browser is told to use a `get` request by your form, which is why you get Sinatra's little "ditty" page.

Comment: I derived to that solution following this question-answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5747670/simple-search-with-datamapper-and-sinatra?rq=1

Am I in the wrong path?

Thank you for the patience with me.

Comment: What Tin Man is saying is that you have the form sending an HTTP GET, but you have told Sinatra to create a HTTP POST handler for the path `/search`. The referenced question-answer comments did have a bug, the `<form action="/search" method="post">` was correct and should not be changed. Once you have that working, Sinatra should invoke your search action. It will create an array of posts as @post, but your view is expecting an array called @results. You will want to fix this as well.

Comment: I fixed both the issues you advised me, I'm sending HTTP POST from the form, and also Sinatra to create HTTP POST handler for the path _/search_. Also, my array names are similar now. But I'm receiving the error 'undefined method `like' for :Title:Symbol'. THANK YOU IN ADVANCE.

Comment: You should accept this answer and submit another question on how to do a Sequel query with "like"

Comment: Ok, done. Thank you for your help in directing me. Can you also help me about this now please: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20474810/how-to-do-a-sequel-query-with-like