# How to do a Sequel query with 'like'?

Tags: ruby, sinatra, sequel

I'm trying to implement a form to search through the title of my posts.

This is the controller code:

```
post '/search'  do
@results = Post.all(:Title.like => "%#{params[:query]}%")
erb :layout 
end
```

This is the layout.erb code:

```
<form action="/search" method="post">
 <input type="text" name="query"/><br />   
 <input type="submit" />
</form>
<% if @results %>
 <table>
  <%@results.each do |r|%>
  <tr valign="top">
  <td><%=r.Title%></td>
  </tr>
  <%end%>
 </table>
<% end %>
```

I get an error saying 'undefined method `like' for: Title: Symbol'.

Comment: Running into the same issue, which should work according to doc (http://sequel.jeremyevans.net/rdoc/classes/Sequel/Model/InstanceMethods.html) - or i mix up dataset and model.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

> @results = DB[:posts].where(Sequel.like(:Title, "%#{params[:query]}%"))

Comment: Would this return `Sequel::Model`s? I would need that in my Padrino app, but are currently stuck on finding out where `DB` is hidden from me ;)

Comment: I am still utterly confused with Dataset/Model, but this helped: `Seminar.grep(:description, '%emei%').all`

Answer (score 2):

`@results = DB[:posts].where{title.like("%#{params[:query]}%")}`

ref.: https://github.com/jeremyevans/sequel/issues/1103